# Making a custom UI

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

When making an iPhone app, how do I create a custom UI like that seen in the iPhone notes app, Bjango apps, Dayta and others.

For instance: the iPhone Notes app has a leather look and texture/feel to it. And I've seen quite a few apps with this. How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are primarily looking to do is apply a texture to the navigation bar and tool bar. Try a tutorial like this:

http://oneweekapp.com/log/custom-navigation-bar-texture/

Other than that, it is just a custom image for a UITableView background (and some custom cells).